# Embed google spreadsheets without publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wan't to Embed google spreadsheets without publishing, this file set only me access.

I try like this :

```
function viewSheet(idSheet){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSheet);
  var idSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + idSheet + "/pubhtml#gid=" + idSheet2;
  return url ;

}
```

i don't wan't like this.

[image: The result failed]

i wan't like this, this is i use publish in menu: "FILE -> Publish to the web" and i have URL not use code above !

[image: Desired results]

P/s: Sorry my english is a bit poor, please guide me fix it !!!

Comment: You want to publish without manually clicking on publish? Try [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions#publish_a_revision)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for sharing my knowledge, it was very helpful !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to publish to the Web with Apps Script

- Your code attempts to retrieve the link to the published to the web version of the spreadsheet
- However, before using this link, you need to enable the publishing first
- This can be done with specifying the respective parameters of `Drive revisions`
- Once you enabled publishing you can retrieve the link as you did before, however you should change the URL from

`var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + idSheet + "/pubhtml#gid=" + idSheet2;`

to

`var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pubhtml?key=" + idSheet + "&gid=" + idSheet2 + "&single=true";`

**Sample:**

```
function viewSheet(idSheet){
  var revisionsList = Drive.Revisions.list(idSheet);  
  var revisions = revisionsList.items; 
  var revisionId =revisions[revisions.length-1].id; 
  var lastRevision = Drive.Revisions.get(idSheet, revisionId); 
  lastRevision.published = true;
  lastRevision.publishAuto = true;
  lastRevision.publishedOutsideDomain = true;
  Drive.Revisions.update(lastRevision, idSheet, revisionId); 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSheet);
  var idSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pubhtml?key=" + idSheet + "&gid=" + idSheet2 + "&single=true";
  return url ;

}
```

- Be aware that for accessing `Drive revisions` you need to [enable the advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) `Drive`

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I have tried and been successful. Thank you very much !!!!